# Replace particular strings in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace all occurrences of "W32 L30" with "W32in L30in" in a large corpus of text. The numbers after W, L also vary.

I thought of using this regex expressions

```
[W]([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)
[L]([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)
```

But these would only find the number after each W and L, so it's still laborious and very time consuming to replace every occurrence so I was wondering if there's a way to do this directly in regex.

Comment: The numbers can be floats as well?

Comment: yes, they can be floats as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capture group and simplify the regex. Next we can then use a *backref* to do the replacement. Like:

```
import re

RGX = re.compile(r'([WL]([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+))(in)?')
result = RGX.sub(r'\1in', some_string)
```

The `\1` is used to reference the first capture group: the result of the string we capture with `[WL]([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)`. The last part `(in)?` optionally also matches the word `in`, such that in case there is already an `in`, we simply replace it with the same value.

So if `some_string` is for instance:

```
>>> some_string
'A W2 in C3.15 where L2.4in and a bit A4'
>>> RGX.sub(r'\1in', some_string)
'A W2in in C3.15 where L2.4in and a bit A4'
```

Comment: thanks this is great, but what happens if I use `some_string="W32in L45"`? I would get `"W32inin L45in"`, but instead I would like `"W32in L45in"`

Comment: @Brian: only if it ends with `in`? What happens if it would be `W32out`?

Comment: only if it ends with in